# HTML Content pushed down below a fixed background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page starts (first thing after the `<body>` tag) with this:

```
<div id="wallpaper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1;">
    <img src="images/black-matte-1650-Lit-Etched.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" alt="">
</div>
```

This works fine on every browser except IE when it is in Compatibility View mode.  Even most IE version display this correctly, but only if not in Compatibility View mode.

The content is supposed to "hover" over the background image so that as the page scrolls, the content scrolls, but the background remains stationary.  Instead, the rest of the page's contents are pushed down to the bottom of the background image, and they render from there.  So, my page appears to be nothing but it's background image, and you have to scroll down to see the page content below it.

Can anyone explain what is wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: I see an image but no background image.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not setting the background image on the `<body`> element? What happens if you make the `position` of that div absolute?

Comment: A quick google would solve this in a matter of seconds. Or a stackoverflow search for that matter. Anyway, see e.g. http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position-background-image

Comment: you are probably putting IE into a quirks mode which doesnt allow position:fixed

Comment: Roope, the article link was good, but didn't address fitting the size of the background to the visible area of the browser (Which is what my posted code is doing).  

But commenters, at the bottom DID address that by suggesting the body be styled thus:

background: url(a.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: fixed;

However, again, that produces a problem for IE Compatibility View mode.  It doesn't resize the image to fit the background.  --edit: SO's comments, it seems, strip out all line breaks.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a fixed background image, I would not use a div. Try this instead...

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background:url(images/black-matte-1650-Lit-Etched.jpg) top right no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed; 
}
```

Then remove your wallpaper div and image from the HTML.

Edit: You could also apply that CSS to your div if that div needs a different background than the rest of the page:

```
div#wallpaper{
    background:url(images/black-matte-1650-Lit-Etched.jpg) top right no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed; 
}
```

Comment: The way I'm doing it causes the background to stretch/shrink to fit the visible area.  Can your idea be implemented and also fit the image to the browser?